# setModalTransitionStyle and setModalPresentationStyle, set size of view

Tags: objective-c, ios, uimodalpresentationstyle

I create a UIViewController (a custom calendar and its size is 550x440) and when i push a button it must be appear; the problem is that if I use setModalPresentationStyle and setModalTransitionStyle they change size of my view; can I set the size for these presentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find a solution:

```
[self presentModalViewController:calendar animated:YES];

calendar.view.superview.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200);
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want to change your design to implement your calendar as a popover:

```
// Define the size of the calendar view controller for the popover
UIViewController *viewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
viewController.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(550.0f, 440.0f);
viewController.delegate = self;

UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController];
navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;

// Create the popover
UIPopoverController *popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:navigationController];

// Present the popover from one button
[popoverController presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:button permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown animated:YES];

//release the popover content
[viewController release];
[navigationController release];
```